# how to pass object to constructor by ref or pointer?

Tags: c++

Something goes wrong here and I can't understand what that is.

There is my class

```cpp
class EmulatorCameraMng : BaseCameraManager
{
public:
    EmulatorCameraMng(EmulatorCameraConfigParser & parser) : m_parser(&parser) {};
    ~EmulatorCameraMng() {};

public:
    void load_configuration_from(const std::string & json_config_file_name);

private:
    EmulatorCameraConfigParser * m_parser;
    std::vector<emulator_context::EmulatorContextObj> * m_emulator_context_objects;
};
```

It take a `parser` as a param in the constructor.

Now, I need to create this `EmulatorCameraMng` obj and pass this `parser`:

```cpp
EmulatorCameraConfigParser m_parser;
camera_manager::EmulatorCameraMng m_emulator_manager(m_parser);
```

Actually, what I want to do is pass object to another object as a param in a constructor without calling a copy constructor. So, there are two ways, by reference or by pointer, but neither of them work.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. What you’ve got here is C++, not C.  I’ve fixed the tag for you, but please be careful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler tnx, do you have any suggestions about the how I can solve my issue?

Comment: No.  I mostly leave C++ questions for other people to answer. My C++ isn’t good enough in modern C++ to want to pontificate.

Comment: It may also be that intellisense has hickups. Please try to compile and show us the compiler errors, if there are any. Also it looks somewhat dangerous that you store a pointer to a local variable here.

Comment: Where is `camera_manager::EmulatorCameraMng m_emulator_manager(m_parser);` ? You can't use that syntax in a class definition

Comment: @bipll Where do you mean? `m_parser(&parser)` is ok.

Comment: Is `EmulatorCameraConfigParser` defined in the namespace `camera_manager`?

Comment: @Caleth yes, it is in class definition, but why I can't use it there? So, where I can use it, just in method body you mean?

Comment: All of these questions about details and clarity clearly indicate that your example is **incomplete**. Please provide a **complete, minimal and reproducible** example because there are a lot of missing information here. Moreover, do not rely on intellisense hints but on compiler outputs. intellisense may have been misconfigured sometimes.

Comment: @bipll no, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a class definition, something of the form `camera_manager::EmulatorCameraMng m_emulator_manager(m_parser);` is syntactically a member function declaration. You get an error there because you name an object not a type.

You will need to pass `m_parser` to `m_emulator_manager` in each constructor's member initialiser list, e.g.

```
class Foo {
    EmulatorCameraConfigParser m_parser;
    camera_manager::EmulatorCameraMng m_emulator_manager;
public:
    Foo() : m_emulator_manager(m_parser) {}
}
```